# Load first 3 image elements in HTML, click “load more” to display next 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with id #myList, it contains 8 sub divs with image in each of sub divs.

What i want to do is load first 3 images by default and then when we click on **load more**

I have followed this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_patnala/nFd7C/422/)

My code is below and similar but it's not functioning due to unknown reason

```js
        <div id="mylist" class="autoplay123company">

          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/gtbank__1.jpg" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/partner-MTN.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Partner-airtel.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/page-1.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Partner-citibank.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

            <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

            <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

            <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
        <div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

```css
#myList div.col-lg-4 {
  display: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="mylist" class="autoplay123company">

  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

    <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/gtbank__1.jpg" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

    <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/partner-MTN.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

    <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Partner-airtel.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

    <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/page-1.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

    <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Partner-citibank.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

    <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

    <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

    <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

  </div>
</div>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

Please help me achieve it. Here is [my edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/1970/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it worked a simple mistake in id capitalization #myList in Html

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList div.col-lg-4").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList div.col-lg-4:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList div.col-lg-4:lt('+x+')').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList div.col-lg-4').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
        $('#loadMore').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == 3){
            $('#showLess').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#myList div.col-lg-4 {
  display: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
        <div id="myList" class="autoplay123company">

          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/gtbank__1.jpg" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/partner-MTN.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Partner-airtel.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/page-1.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">

            <img src=" http://realbusinessanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Partner-citibank.png" alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

            <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

            <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

            <img src=" " alt="" style="height:100px !important;" width="150" height="100">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
        <div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

Here is the [Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/1981/). Thanks Macros

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to `#myList` in the JS and CSS however the div is actually `mylist`.  If you correct the casing on the div ID then all should work as expected.

Comment: Currently the mechanism is for the first three it adds inline css display:block;  , and for the hidden one it is display:none;   at last when we click load more it does add display:block;  . Can we Change it to add dispaly:flex; by default and then onclick load more it should add display:flex;  ??. can you please guide me?